# material_segmented_control in combination with futures

Tags: flutter

i made a friendspage, where i want to show the user in the correct segment the correct data.
so i made 3 futures (requests, subscribers and subscriptions)

in my mind the handling with the if over the futures is not the best, but i dont know a better way..

the problem is that if i switch from tab to tab, the future has data from the tab before in its values..

is there some kind of clear which i should do before switching the tab, or is there a more elegant way to solve this without the large if content?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:material_segmented_control/material_segmented_control.dart';
//Screens
import '../screens/friendssearch.dart';
//Services
import '../services/api_friends.dart';
//Models
import '../models/friendspending.dart';
import '../models/friendsapproved.dart';
import '../models/friendsuser.dart';

class FriendsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFriendsPageState createState() => _MyFriendsPageState();
}

class _MyFriendsPageState extends State<FriendsPage> {
  Future<List<FriendsPending>> myFriendsPending;
  Future<List<FriendsApproved>> mySubscriptions;
  Future<List<FriendsUser>> mySubscribers;
  int _currentSelection = 0;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFriendsPending = FriendsApi().getFriendRequests();
    mySubscriptions = FriendsApi().getSubscriptions();
    mySubscribers = FriendsApi().getSubscribers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Friends'), actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () => {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FriendsSearchPage()))
            },
          )
        ]),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
              MaterialSegmentedControl(
                horizontalPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                verticalOffset: 12,
                children: _children,
                selectionIndex: _currentSelection,
                borderColor: Colors.grey,
                selectedColor: Colors.green,
                unselectedColor: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: 8.0,
                disabledChildren: _disabledIndices,
                onSegmentChosen: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentSelection = index;
                  });
                },
              ),
              if (_currentSelection == 0) ...[
                FutureBuilder<List>(
                    future: myFriendsPending,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error, while loading friends');
                      }
                      List friendspending = snapshot.data ?? []; <-- here are the wrong values of the tab before in the snapshot
                      return Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: friendspending.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                FriendsPending friend = friendspending[index];
                                return new ListTile(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    title: new Text(friend.user),
                                    subtitle: new Text(
                                        friend.userdata.firstname + ' ' + friend.userdata.lastname),
                                    leading: ClipOval(
                                      child: friend.userdata.image == '' ||
                                              friend.userdata.image == null
                                          ? CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 28,
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                              backgroundImage:
                                                  AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png'))
                                          : CachedNetworkImage(
                                              width: 56,
                                              height: 56,
                                              imageUrl: friend.userdata.image + '?w=200&h=200',
                                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                                  Icon(Icons.error),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    trailing: SizedBox(
                                        height: 35,
                                        child: FlatButton(
                                            onPressed: () => pressAddFriendButton(friend.user),
                                            child: Text('Accept',
                                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)),
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87)))),
                                    dense: false);
                              }));
                    })
              ] else if (_currentSelection == 1) ...[
                FutureBuilder<List>(
                    future: mySubscriptions,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      List subscriptions = snapshot.data ?? []; <-- here are the wrong values of the tab before in the snapshot
                      return Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: subscriptions.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                FriendsApproved friend = subscriptions[index];
                                return new ListTile(
                                    title: new Text(friend.userdata.sId),
                                    subtitle: new Text(
                                        friend.userdata.firstname + ' ' + friend.userdata.lastname),
                                    leading: ClipOval(
                                      child: friend.userdata.image == '' ||
                                              friend.userdata.image == null
                                          ? CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 28,
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                              backgroundImage:
                                                  AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png'))
                                          : CachedNetworkImage(
                                              width: 56,
                                              height: 56,
                                              imageUrl: friend.userdata.image + '?w=200&h=200',
                                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                                  Icon(Icons.error),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    trailing: SizedBox(
                                        height: 35,
                                        child: FlatButton(
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                pressRemoveSubscriptionButton(friend.userdata.sId),
                                            child: Text('Remove',
                                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)),
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87)))),
                                    dense: false);
                              }));
                    }),
              ] else if (_currentSelection == 2) ...[
                FutureBuilder<List>(
                    future: mySubscribers,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      List subscribers = snapshot.data ?? []; <-- here are the wrong values of the tab before in the snapshot
                      return Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: subscribers.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                FriendsUser friend = subscribers[index];
                                return new ListTile(
                                    title: new Text(friend.userdata.sId),
                                    subtitle: new Text(
                                        friend.userdata.firstname + ' ' + friend.userdata.lastname),
                                    leading: ClipOval(
                                      child: friend.userdata.image == '' ||
                                              friend.userdata.image == null
                                          ? CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 28,
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                              backgroundImage:
                                                  AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png'))
                                          : CachedNetworkImage(
                                              width: 56,
                                              height: 56,
                                              imageUrl: friend.userdata.image + '?w=200&h=200',
                                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                                  Icon(Icons.error),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    trailing: SizedBox(
                                        height: 35,
                                        child: FlatButton(
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                pressRemoveSubscriberButton(friend.userdata.sId),
                                            child: Text('Remove',
                                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)),
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87)))),
                                    dense: false);
                              }));
                    })
              ]
            ])));
  }

  Map<int, Widget> _children = {
    0: Text('  Requests  '),
    1: Text('  Subscriptions  '),
    2: Text('  Subscribers  '),
  };

  List<int> _disabledIndices = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `Key` on the `FutureBuilder` so that flutter knows you are referring to a different builder instance. Without the key it sees the same type of widget and uses the cached version to cut down on rebuilding (since it thinks it has not changed). With the key it will know each `FutureBuilder` is different.

```
if (_currentSelection == 0) ...[
    FutureBuilder<List>(
        key: ValueKey(0),
        future: myFriendsPending,
        ...
    )]
else if (_currentSelection == 1) ...[
    FutureBuilder<List>(
        key: ValueKey(1),
        future: mySubscriptions,
        ...
    )]
else if (_currentSelection == 2) ...[
    FutureBuilder<List>(
        key: ValueKey(2),
        future: mySubscribers,
        ...
    )]
```

Comment: thank you i will try this too.. meanwhile i found a solution with Visibility() .. i create all 3 widgets and control 3 boolean variables which controls the visibility of the 3 futures